# SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /account/login has not been defined

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere-7

I am using Eclipse Luna and IBM Websphere 7. I have deployed EAR into WAS7. After starting the server I am getting below error.

[11/18/15 10:30:35:226 HST] 00000000 WsServerImpl  A   WSVR0001I: Server server1 open for e-business
[11/18/15 10:30:38:518 HST] 0000000f SystemErr     R Cannot load XSL files from C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\plugins\com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar
[11/18/15 10:30:38:520 HST] 0000000f SystemErr     R Cannot load XSL files from C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\plugins\com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar
[11/18/15 10:30:38:521 HST] 0000000f SystemErr     R Cannot load XSL files from C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\plugins\com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar
[11/18/15 10:30:38:522 HST] 0000000f SystemErr     R Cannot load XSL files from C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\plugins\com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar
[11/18/15 10:30:39:169 HST] 00000010 WorkSpaceMana A   WKSP0500I: Workspace configuration consistency check is disabled.
[11/18/15 10:35:22:441 HST] 0000001e webcontainer  E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer handleRequest SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /account/login has not been defined.

Comment: anything else to add? some code?

Comment: I am deploying enterprise application into was7 and getting above error. It was working fine before. let me know if you need additional details I can add more console log.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with context-root in application.xml
There was a mismatch in EAR for web-uri to context-root.